# What do you call it when you are saying something palpably untrue on purpose?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call it when you say something ridiculous and untrue on purpose to make a point? In this case it's clear that you don't really mean it, and you don't mean to lie / misdirect.

I want to say *fallacious* but that's not exactly it.

Comment: Don't we call that lying?

Comment: @tchrist The question specifically says "you don't mean to lie/misdirect". Lying is done with intent to deceive.

Comment: Exaggeration, or reductio ad absurdum...

Comment: Can you add an example of what might be said in a context (including the tone of voice)?

Comment: *Tongue in cheek* or *facetious*? *"If you say something tongue in cheek, you intend it to be understood as a joke, although you might appear to be serious: He said that he was a huge fan of the president, although I suspect it was tongue in cheek."* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tongue-in-cheek

Comment: *Sarcasm* is a type of this, *irony*, *proof by contradiction*, *pious fraud*, and the already mentioned *reductio ad absurdum*, and possibly other terms. This is why it helps to have an example rather than leave us guessing.

Comment: Give an example.

Comment: Depending on the example, you might have a point and you might not 

Comment: Surely you're talking about either sarcasm or irony ?

Comment: @Fattie one difference between facetiousness and sarcasm is the former is light-hearted, while the latter can be offensive. I chose the former for my answer because of OP's apparent requirement for humour, from 'ridiculous', which somehow isn't the 'ridicule' that sarcasm can be.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you mention 'ridiculous' perhaps **facetious** will work.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/facetious) has

> not serious about a serious subject, in an attempt to be funny or to appear clever

Often people will make a facetious remark not to be silly, but to make a point.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Off the subject, but one of two words containing all the vowels - in alphabetical order.

Comment: @Tim — With *facetiously* you get the "sometimes *y*" vowel in there alphabetically too.

Comment: @Tim There's actually [a lot more than 2 of them](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_that_use_all_vowels_in_alphabetical_order).  It's probably the most well-known example though.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - wow., never realised that . I guess there are two of them in more common use - facetious and abstemious - never even heard of most of the others. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim phrases as well, for instance 'Lawn tennis court'

Comment: @ventsyv it doesn't gel with your use of "untrue" in the headline.  If I say something facetiously the point is ***in my opinion*** it is incredibly untrue.  An example from below *"Bob was being facetious when he said that the queen was a great paragon of virtue"* but note that, indeed, any number of people do think HM was a paragon of virtue. (Thus, "Monarchist Matt was being facetious when he said that the queen was a lazy slob...")  Facetious statements have nothing to do with being **untrue**, they are a humorous/sarcastic way to give **your opinion**.

Comment: @Tim as an abstemious and never facetious person, thank you so much for that info!  I had no idea about that.  Awesome.

Comment: (btw I am literally abstemious and never facetious - I wasn't being, uh, facetious there!)

Answer (score 5):

You are being *hyperbolic*:

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hyperbolic)

> of, relating to, or marked by language that exaggerates or overstates the truth : of, relating to, or marked by hyperbole

Or using *hyperbole*:

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hyperbole)

> hy·​per·​bo·​le | \ hī-ˈpər-bə-(ˌ)lē  \

> Definition of hyperbole
> : extravagant exaggeration (such as "mile-high ice-cream cones")

Comment: You know, hyperbole is "true" but ridiculously exaggerated.  I don't think that's what the OP means.

Answer (score 3):

When you intentionally say the opposite of what you mean, it’s called *verbal irony.*

> According to A glossary of literary terms by Abrams and Harpham,

> Verbal irony is a statement in which the meaning that a speaker employs is sharply different from the meaning that is ostensibly expressed. An ironic statement usually involves the explicit expression of one attitude or evaluation, but with indications in the overall speech-situation that the speaker intends a very different, and often opposite, attitude or evaluation.

> In a clear example from literature, in Shakespeare's Julius Caesar, Mark Antony's speech after the assassination of Caesar appears to praise the assassins, particularly Brutus ("But Brutus says he was ambitious; / And Brutus is an honourable man"), while actually condemning them. "We're left in no doubt as to who's ambitious and who's honourable. The literal truth of what's written clashes with the perceived truth of what's meant to revealing effect, which is irony in a nutshell".

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony

Verbal irony may or may not be sarcastic, as the cited article notes.

Verbal irony is common in everyday conversation.

Answer (score 2):

**sarcasm**

harsh, cutting, or bitter derision, often using irony to point out the deficiencies or failings of someone or something:

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sarcasm

And the adjective would be *sarcastic*.

Answer (score 0):

*reductio ad absurdum*

“the form of argument that attempts to establish a claim by showing that the opposite scenario would lead to absurdity or contradiction”

The Wikipedia article that I took this from has several examples.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum

In this way of speaking, the person making the argument intends to refute the premises. They do this by showing that they lead to a conclusion that neither the speaker nor the listener believe to be true.

Alternatively, the OP may be looking for a form of expression where the truth is exaggerated, as in advertising: “Want to be the smartest person in the room? Want to own the party?”

This is *hyperbole*, where the Wikipedia is also helpful, and provides some other words which may be helpful in their own way (see paragraph above).

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole

Comment: I would not class the *reducto ad absurdum* as an untruth. The argument to show A is false does not state that A is true, but that **if** A is true then so is B, and since we all know B is false, A must be false.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily the best answer, but it's a related concept worth bringing up. The asker did say the purpose was "to make a point". Would sarcastically stating an absurd conclusion that follows from something ridiculous not qualify as both?

Answer (score -2):

"*disinform*" comes to mind.
Twitter is impressively good at disseminating disinformation.

Comment: OP asks for something that you don't intend to lie or misdirect. I think disinform means exactly that.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please back up your answer with corroboration from a dictionary or two. This is necessary for any answer, but particularly when doubt has been expressed via comments or votes.